# How to implicitly convert one implicit variable to another implicit variable in scala

Tags: scala

all

I have function A and B like this:

```
def B(implicit t2: T2) = {
    ....
}

def A(implicit t1: T1) = {
    B()
}
```

T1 and T2 are different types. 
How to implicitly convert implicit variable t1 to implicit variable t2?

Best Regards,
Kevin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an implicit materializer (an implicit def without parameter) returning type `T2`, that requires an implicit parameter of type `T1`:

```
implicit def autoConvert(implicit t1: T1): T2 =
  // your conversion
```

Then, if you have this implicit in scope, as well as an implicit `T1`, it can generate an implicit `T2` using that conversion.

Use sparingly ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the value direct:

```
def expectInt(implicit i: Int) = i * 10 

def expectString(implicit s: String) = { 
  expectInt(Integer.parseInt(s))       
}

expectsString("3") yields 30
```

---

If you can't change the method call: use a implicit conversion:

```
// EXAMPLE CODE - WITHOUT EXCEPTION HANDLING!!
implicit def s2i(s: String) =   Integer.parseInt(s)          

def expectInt(implicit i: Int) = i * 10                      

def expectString(implicit s: String) = {                                              
  expectInt(s)                                               
}            

implicit val s = "2"                                
expectString yields 20
```

**but keep in mind: to much implicit conversions doesn't make your code easy to understand**